# expanded table view cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to open more information in small view of every cell selection , like exapnding able view cell.i am taaching screen shot also. I am not able to dot this plase help.How it can be done!
[image: want to open blak view on each cell and remaining cell exapnded below]

I am using below code , it is working fine but how to show hidden view on particular cell position

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath {

 // Deselect cell
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:TRUE];

// Toggle 'selected' state
BOOL isSelected = ![self cellIsSelected:indexPath];

// Store cell 'selected' state keyed on indexPath
NSNumber *selectedIndex = [NSNumber numberWithBool:isSelected];
[selectedIndexes setObject:selectedIndex forKey:indexPath];

// This is where magic happens...
[tbleLectures  beginUpdates];
[tbleLectures endUpdates];
 }


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

{
// If our cell is selected, return double height
if([self cellIsSelected:indexPath]) {
    return kCellHeight * 2.0;

 //      return 44;
}

// Cell isn't selected so return single height
return kCellHeight;

 }
```

Comment: You can set return with the right height in the tableview:heightForRowAtIndexPath: method of your tableview delegate. Please provide some code to find out what can be the problem.

Comment: @dave - i have added my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reload your tableview to make it effective or reload just the cell in your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`:

```
// This is where magic happens...
[tbleLectures  beginUpdates];
[tbleLectures reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPathOfYourCell] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[tbleLectures endUpdates];
```

Comment: how we can add view to particular  cell postion

Comment: In the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:.

Comment: OK it works well but how i acn show my additional information

Comment: Implement some logic in the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: to show detail info too, when it is the selected cell.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the height of the cell then you should reload the table view and use

```
    - (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

delegate method to show/hide detail view

another logic is to maintain the state of the tableView and populate cells based on the state of the tableView. The tableView should have isSelectedCell/notSelected state. if tableView is selected then number of returning cell always +1 (One for detail cell); and Insert the detail cell after selected cell. to maintain the index of selected cell you might need class variable.

For this kind of work in iOS you need to have some logic!
Hope this helps

Comment: Can't you create separate nib file for that cell and load that ?